# Has anyone used tables package? or good at making tables?

Tags: r

here is my dataset with 72 row

```
      C   p   n type coverage
1  0.80 0.1   5    1    0.307
2  0.80 0.1  10    1    0.582
3  0.80 0.1  50    1    0.851
4  0.80 0.1 100    1    0.801
5  0.80 0.3   5    1    0.680
6  0.80 0.3  10    1    0.814
7  0.80 0.3  50    1    0.749
8  0.80 0.3 100    1    0.803
9  0.80 0.5   5    1    0.608
10 0.80 0.5  10    1    0.657
```

I want to make it into table using any

```
         C                   
         0.8    0.9    0.95  
         type   type   type  
 p   n   0    1 0    1 0    1
 0.1 5   1    1 1    1 1    1
     10  1    1 1    1 1    1
     50  1    1 1    1 1    1
     100 1    1 1    1 1    1
 0.3 5   1    1 1    1 1    1
     10  1    1 1    1 1    1
     50  1    1 1    1 1    1
     100 1    1 1    1 1    1
 0.5 5   1    1 1    1 1    1
     10  1    1 1    1 1    1
     50  1    1 1    1 1    1
     100 1    1 1    1 1    1
```

So I have 3 levels in C, 3 levels in p, 4 levels in n and 2 levels in type.
I dont know how to put corresponding coverage values in the table above instead of 1.

does anyone know how to make this table?

I used tables packages

```
tabular( Factor(p)*Factor(n) ~ Factor(C)*Factor(type)  , data=finaldatatable)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be try something like (use an appropriate aggregate function sum / mean etc. for coverage):

changed sample data little bit:

```
df
      C   p   n type coverage
1  0.80 0.1   5    1    0.307
2  0.80 0.1  10    1    0.582
3  0.80 0.1  50    1    0.851
4  0.80 0.1 100    1    0.801
5  0.90 0.3   5    1    0.680
6  0.90 0.3  10    1    0.814
7  0.80 0.3  50    1    0.749
8  0.80 0.3 100    1    0.803
9  0.95 0.5   5    1    0.608
10 0.95 0.5  10    1    0.657

tabular( Factor(p)*Factor(n) ~ Factor(C)*Factor(type) + coverage*sum  , data=df)
         C                    
         0.8 0.9 0.95 coverage
 p   n   1   1   1    sum     
 0.1 5   1   0   0    0.307   
     10  1   0   0    0.582   
     50  1   0   0    0.851   
     100 1   0   0    0.801   
 0.3 5   0   1   0    0.680   
     10  0   1   0    0.814   
     50  1   0   0    0.749   
     100 1   0   0    0.803   
 0.5 5   0   0   1    0.608   
     10  0   0   1    0.657   
     50  0   0   0    0.000   
     100 0   0   0    0.000
```

Also, something like

```
tabular( Factor(p)*Factor(n) * Factor(C)*Factor(type) ~  coverage*sum, data=df)         

                coverage
 p   n   C      sum     
 0.1 5   0.8  1 0.307   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     10  0.8  1 0.582   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     50  0.8  1 0.851   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     100 0.8  1 0.801   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
 0.3 5   0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.680   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     10  0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.814   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     50  0.8  1 0.749   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     100 0.8  1 0.803   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
 0.5 5   0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.608   
     10  0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.657   
     50  0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000   
     100 0.8  1 0.000   
         0.9  1 0.000   
         0.95 1 0.000
```

or may be this one:

```
tabular( Factor(p)*Factor(n) ~ Factor(C)*Factor(type) * coverage*sum  , data=df)
         C                         
         0.8      0.9      0.95    
         1        1        1       
         coverage coverage coverage
 p   n   sum      sum      sum     
 0.1 5   0.307    0.000    0.000   
     10  0.582    0.000    0.000   
     50  0.851    0.000    0.000   
     100 0.801    0.000    0.000   
 0.3 5   0.000    0.680    0.000   
     10  0.000    0.814    0.000   
     50  0.749    0.000    0.000   
     100 0.803    0.000    0.000   
 0.5 5   0.000    0.000    0.608   
     10  0.000    0.000    0.657   
     50  0.000    0.000    0.000   
     100 0.000    0.000    0.000
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can actually put the coverage values in the middle of the table....

Comment: Instead of those 1 and 0 in the middle, there must be some ways to put coverage values in the corresponding place

Comment: Yes, the last one gave me something very close to what I want! Thank you very much bro

Comment: never had come across this fucntion. Thanks for this answer.